# AdMob ads don't show up with Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I followed a tutorial about building an android app and everything works fine except the part with the ads. I've exported the apk to my phone but I can't see any banner in my game.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class Admob : MonoBehaviour
{
private BannerView bannerView;
private void RequestBanner()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-87275346751xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
    string adUnitId = "";
#else
    string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif
    bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    }
void Start()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    string appId = "ca-app-pub-87275346751xxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"; //your admob app id 
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
    string appId = "";
#else
    string appId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

    // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
    MobileAds.Initialize(appId);
    //MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
    RequestRewardedAd();
    RequestInterstitial();
    RequestBanner();
    ShowBanner();

    }
}
public void ShowBanner()
{
    bannerView.Show();
}
```

This is the script for the ads. Regarding the Start method, I tried the `MobileAds.Initialize(appId)` function, exactly like the guy from the tutorial, but the Unity said the method was deprecated so I should use `Initialize(Action<InitializationStatus> initCompleteAction)` instead, so I tried `MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });`. Both don't work.
I went through some topics here and there were guys that said they are able to see test ads inside their games, but I can't even see them. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using test unit IDs for Admob ads? Please first make sure ads with test unit IDs work. Using your own ad unit IDs for showing ads while testing can lead to permanent ban.

After getting test ads to work you can be sure your code is alright. To be able to show real ads in app/game you must first setup payment information on Admob (you don't need to set up credit card, just the main information about you).

Also I would recommend to make use of events for "AdFailedToShow" and "AdFailedToLoad" to know what went wrong. Ideally you must use test ad unit IDs for testing and when everything is working you change them with your own unit IDs, then build the game and upload it to Google Play Store. You can show real ads on your own device, but you must not click them. It is against the policies.

If there is "Internal Error" message on loading real ads but not on test ads, most likely your payment info on Admob is not set up. But most of the time there is "No Fill" error, which means AdMob was unable to get an ad for you (basically means there is no ads for you in inventory right now), it is going to be fixed when people start playing your game and requesting ads.

Comment: Yes, I've managed somehow to solve half of the problem and now the test ads work, but the real ones don't. Why should I get banned if I want to show real ads? Is this a problem? Or should I change the ads from test ones to real ones only when I add the app to play store?